# Android Emulator appears not to trust Security Certificates in Browser

Tags: android, ssl, android-emulator, certificate

So I am running a few automated tests on an android emulator. I have two environments, my development PC running the android emulator, and our testing server running the android emulator. When I open the emulator and the browser app within the emulator, I can navigate to secure websites no problem. (For instance, google mail). However, in my testing server environment, I am seeing certificate errors on sites whose certificates should well be trusted. Is there an emulator configuration option for certificates that I am missing? Does the emulator need to connect to a service to verify the certificates and does not have access?

[image: SSL certificate reads not from a trusted auth even though it's google, for pete's sake.]

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the date and time are set properly on the emulator.  An incorrect time setting may well invalidate the certificate because it's not within validity window.